# File Control Block architecture

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share, windows-server-2012

Our site runs its main business application (delphi 5) from a network share, this caused quite a bit of chaos when we upgraded our terminal servers to 2008 R2 from 2003 as [MS changed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2536487) the architecture in 2008 of how it handles FCB, so the FCB got orphaned when the user with the FCB logged off.

We managed to keep it stable by creating a DFS for the share which eliminated most of the issues (still get randomly the Access violation that doesn't always show as a code issue)

Our next roll out to server 2012 starts soon, does anyone know how 2012 handles the redirector for FCB?

Comment: You next roll out "starts soon", and you haven't tested this?  Sounds like the same plan that blew up for the 2008 R2 upgrade.

Comment: Why didn't you use the published workaround, WebDAV?

Answer (score 0):

Never tested it in a production enviroment only in a lab so far , but you can customize error messages and also use DAC (which is new for Windows Server 2012 ) http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowsserver/archive/2012/05/22/introduction-to-windows-server-2012-dynamic-access-control.aspx , everything seems to be much better but making a lab or testing before hand might be the best path , especially for a business critical application .

You could also use Scale-Out File Server http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831349.aspx .